# Tab completion doesn't work for arguments when command is an alias

Tags: bash, autocomplete

I have an alias, ee, defined for my favorite editor, mg. When I do something like

```
mg fo
```

and then hit tab, if a file foo exists, I get tab completion to:

```
mg foo
```

On most systems I use (e.g., all versions of ubuntu for many years now, and some installs of debian),

```
ee fo
```

also completes properly to

```
ee foo
```

But on one system I use, which has Debian 6.0 and GNU bash 4.1.5(1)-release, tab completion fails for the version with the alias. Note that this is *not* a problem with completing the alias itself -- it's a problem with completing the *arguments* of the aliased command. Is there a way to fix this behavior on the Debian system? Upgrade to bash 4.2.x? Fiddle with config files?

Comment: Do you have the bash-completion package installed? Are you sourcing `/etc/bash_completion`?

Comment: @jordanm: Yes, bash-completion is installed. I don't know if I'm sourcing /etc/bash_completion automatically for each login session, but I'm guessing that I am somewhere, because $BASH_COMPLETION is defined. If I do an explicit "source /etc/bash_completion" it doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: OK. Seems like I might have misread the situation. Thought you meant program options as in:

```
$ mplayer_alias -pla<tab><tab>
-playing-msg  -playlist
$
```

but guess it is file completion. I don't know, but give it a go.

As a quick fix this should work:

```
complete -f -o default ee
```

Giving:

```
$ ee<tab><tab>
file1 file2 file3
$
```

as of [Programmable Completion Builtins](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Programmable-Completion-Builtins.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins). E.g. the `-X pattern` can be useful. E.g. to exclude `.swp` and `.swo` files:

```
complete -f -X '*.sw[op]' ee
```

only show `.zip`, `.ZIP`:

```
complete -f -o default -X '!*.+(zip|ZIP)' my_unzip_alias
```

some might need you to add `shopt -s extglob` in configuration file.

---

---

OLD Answer:

You could try out something like this in your `.bash_completion`.

*At least as a starter.*

The core idea is to simply add `complete` for the alias using the existing
complete script for the *real* program. Here I assume that they are all in the format:

```
complete -F _complete_function_from_original program_name
```

You can get what it is by executing: `complete -p program_name`. Best to check first.

For some methods like `apt-get` one can use only alias + load:

```
_load_comp_hack apt-get myalias
```

For others like `mplayer` one need a function wrapper, as in e.g.:

```
myalias() { mplayer "$@"; }
                      |
                      +--- Could be messy
```

It is quite possible there is a better way to solve this, but has worked fine for my use. I mostly use it for wrapper scripts where I extend the functionality of the original program. Have not used it on aliases.

I do not feel to safe on this hack, but you could see if it works.

```
_load_comp_hack()
{
    local cc=
    # Make sure completion scripts are sourced.
    # Report error if source fail.
    if . "/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/$1" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        # Extract the completion function used by the "real" program.
        if cc="$(complete -p "$1" | cut -d' ' -f3)"; then
            # Add it to the alias
            complete -F "$cc" "$2"
            return 0
        fi
    fi
    echo "bash-completion '$1' for '$2' not found."
}

_load_comp_hack mplayer mplad
_load_comp_hack apt-get z
                |       |
                |       +----- Alias, script or function
                +------------- Real function
```

Some programs use more general completion like `_longopt`, by which the
source file won't be located. Usually it is no need to source either, so a
simpler variant could be:

```
_load_comp_hack()
{
    local cc=
    if cc=$(complete -p "$1" | cut -d' ' -f3); then
            complete -F "$cc" "$2"
    fi
}
```

One problem here, IIRC, is that some completion scripts are not loaded until first run, as in first:
 `prog` <kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>tab</kbd>. As an alternative perhaps add it as an `else` if sourcing of file fails.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The real program does not seem to have its own completion defined; `complete -p mg` gives no result. And yet I get tab completion when I use the real program ...?

Comment: @BenCrowell: Completions as in program options, not files?

Comment: @BenCrowell: Updated answer. Is it correct now?

Comment: Great, `complete -f -o default ee` is a fix. +1, answer accepted. Further testing also shows that the original problem was only occurring when there were multiple possible completions that were fairly long; under these conditions, mg was doing completion but ee wasn't. After doing `complete -f -o default ee`, ee works the same way on long completions as mg.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is: bash-completion doesn't understand aliases. So if you write an alias, it's simply seen as an unknown command and won't be auto-completed. You can either fallback to default filename completion, if this is what you want. Or, you can install [a program](https://github.com/cykerway/complete-alias) which expands aliases before auto-completion and complete your aliases as their aliased commands.